# How to get value from one function to another function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have to function where one function is call_back function. Now i want to get value (value from "$iamge_location" variable) into another function. i am trying to return the value from callback function and print it into another function from where callback function is called. but i did not get the value plz help..

Here is My controller code:

```
    function RoomImageAdd(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('roomImage', 'Upload Image', 'callback_upload_Image');

        $roomid = $this->input->post('roomid');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->addRoomImage($roomid);
        }
        else {
            echo $image_location;
        }
    }

    function upload_Image(){

        if(!empty($_FILES['roomImage']['name']))
        {
            $filename = date('YmdHis');

            $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/img/upload/rooms/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg';
            $config['file_name'] = $filename;
            $config['max_size'] = '2000';
            $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
            $config['overwrite'] = false;

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('roomImage'))
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('upload_Image', $this->upload->display_errors('',''));
                return FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                $image_data = $this->upload->data();

                $image_location = 'assets/img/upload/rooms/'.$image_data['file_name'];

                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $image_data['full_path'];
                $config['new_image'] = $image_data['file_path'].'room_thumb/';
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                $config['thumb_marker'] = '_thumb';
                $config['width'] = 280;
                $config['height'] = 280;

                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

                if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {

                    $error = array('error' => $this->image_lib->display_errors());

                } else {

                    $this->image_lib->resize();
                }
                return $image_location;
            }
        }
        else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('upload_Image', "Unexpected Error! No File Selected!");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: make variable as global and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you should be able to add a field variable `image_location` which you can set in your `update_Image` function.

Change

```
return $image_location;
```

to

```
$this->image_location = $image_location;
return true; // because a boolean is expected off of a validation callback
```

Now you can use `$this->image_location` to access the location in your `RoomImageAdd` method.